# Boost asio: including <arpa/inet.h> causes socket to always output 0 bytes

Tags: boost

I'm trying to include <arpa/inet.h> in a low-level library so that I have access to hton* and ntoh* functions in the library. The low-level library gets called into by higher-level code running a Boost asio socket. I'm aware Boost asio contains the hton* and ntoh* functions, but i'd like to avoid linking all of Boost asio to the library since hton*/ntoh* are all I need.

However, if I simply include <arpa/inet.h> in the low-level library, 0 bytes always will be sent from the Boost asio socket. Confirmed by Wireshark.

Here's the class where i'd like to include <arpa/inet.h> but not Boost. If <arpa/inet.h> is included, 0 bytes will be sent.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

#include "PduHeader.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>

class ClientInfoPdu
{
public:
    ClientInfoPdu(const uint16_t _client_receiver_port)
    {
        set_client_receiver_port(_client_receiver_port);
    }

    PduHeader pdu_header{CLIENT_INFO_PDU, sizeof(client_receiver_port)};


    inline void set_client_receiver_port(const uint16_t _client_receiver_port)
    {
        //client_receiver_port = htons(_client_receiver_port);
        client_receiver_port = _client_receiver_port;
    }

    inline uint16_t get_client_receiver_port()
    {
        return client_receiver_port;
    }

    inline size_t get_total_size()
    {
        return sizeof(PduHeader) + pdu_header.get_pdu_payload_size();
    }

private:
    uint16_t client_receiver_port;
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Here's the higher level code that includes Boost and attempts to send the data via a socket. The printout indicates 5 bytes were sent, however 0 bytes were actually sent.

```
#include "ServerConnectionThread.h"
#include "config/ClientConfig.h"
#include "protocol_common/ClientInfoPdu.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

void ServerConnectionThread::execute()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::endpoint remote_endpoint = 
    udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(SERVER_IP), SERVER_PORT);
    udp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.open(udp::v4());

    ClientInfoPdu client_info_pdu = ClientInfoPdu(RECEIVE_PORT);

    while (true)
    {
        uint16_t total_size = client_info_pdu.get_total_size();
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(&client_info_pdu, total_size), remote_endpoint);
        printf("sent %u bytes\n", total_size);
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

Again, simply removing "#include <arpa/inet.h>" will cause this code to function as expected and send 5 bytes per packet.

Comment: Asio is header-only so there is nothing to [avoid] linking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is `ClientInfoPdu` defined? This looks like it is likely UB:

```
boost::asio::buffer(&client_info_pdu, total_size)
```

The thing is total size is `sizeof(PduHeader) + pdu_header.get_pdu_payload_size()` (so `sizeof(PduHeader) + 2`);

First problem is that you're mixing access modifiers, killing the POD/standard_layout properties of your types.

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<PduHeader> && std::is_trivial_v<PduHeader>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<ClientInfoPdu> && std::is_trivial_v<ClientInfoPdu>);
```

This will fail to compile. Treating the types as POD (as you do) invokes
[Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> This is likely the explanation for the fact that "it stops working" with some changes. It never **worked**: it might just accidentally have appeared to work, but it was undefined behaviour.

It's not easy to achieve POD-ness while still getting the convenience of the
constructors. In fact, I don't think that's possible. In short, if you want to
treat your structs as C-style POD types, make them... C-style POD types.

Another thing: a possible implementation of `PduHeader I
can see working for you looks a bit like so:

```
enum MsgId{CLIENT_INFO_PDU=0x123};
struct PduHeader {
    MsgId id;
    size_t payload_size;
    size_t get_pdu_payload_size() const { return payload_size; }
};
```

Here, again you might have/need endianness conversions.

### Suggestion

In short, if you want this to work, I'd say keep it simple.

Instead of creating non-POD types all over the place that are responsible for endianness conversion by adding getters/setters for each value, why not create a simple user-defined-type that does this always, and use them instead?

```
struct PduHeader {
    Short id; // or e.g. uint8_t
    Long payload_size;
};

struct ClientInfoPdu {
    PduHeader pdu_header; // or inheritance, same effect
    Short client_receiver_port;
};
```

Then just use it as a POD struct:

```
while (true) {
    ClientInfoPdu client_info_pdu;
    init_pdu(client_info_pdu);

    auto n = socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(&client_info_pdu, sizeof(client_info_pdu)), remote_endpoint);
    printf("sent %lu bytes\n", n);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
```

The function `init_pdu` can be implemented with overloads per submessage:

```
void init_pdu(ClientInfoPdu& msg) {
    msg.pdu_header.id = CLIENT_INFO_PDU;
    msg.pdu_header.payload_size = sizeof(msg);
}
```

> There are variations on this where it can become a template or take a
> `PduHeder&` (if your message inherits instead of aggregates). But the basic
> principle is the same.

### Endianness Conversion

Now you'll noticed I avoided using `uint32_t`/`uint16_t` directly (though `uint8_t` is fine because it doesn't need byte ordering). Instead, you could define `Long` and `Short` as simple POD wrappers around them:

```
struct Short {
    operator uint16_t() const { return ntohs(value); }
    Short& operator=(uint16_t v) { value = htons(v); return *this; }
  private:
    uint16_t value;
};

struct Long {
    operator uint32_t() const { return ntohl(value); }
    Long& operator=(uint32_t v) { value = htonl(v); return *this; }
  private:
    uint32_t value;
};
```

The assignment and conversions mean that you can use it as just another
int32_t/int16_t except that the necessary conversions are always done.

> If you want to satnd on the shoulder of giants instead, you can use **[the better types from Boost Endian](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html)**, which also has lots more advanced facilities

### DEMO

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dddec8ff7e914046)**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

#pragma pack(push, 1)

enum MsgId{CLIENT_INFO_PDU=0x123};

struct Short {
    operator uint16_t() const { return ntohs(value); }
    Short& operator=(uint16_t v) { value = htons(v); return *this; }
  private:
    uint16_t value;
};

struct Long {
    operator uint32_t() const { return ntohl(value); }
    Long& operator=(uint32_t v) { value = htonl(v); return *this; }
  private:
    uint32_t value;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Short>);
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<Short>);

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Long>);
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<Long>);

struct PduHeader {
    Short id; // or e.g. uint8_t
    Long payload_size;
};

struct ClientInfoPdu {
    PduHeader pdu_header; // or inheritance, same effect
    Short client_receiver_port;
};

void init_pdu(ClientInfoPdu& msg) {
    msg.pdu_header.id = CLIENT_INFO_PDU;
    msg.pdu_header.payload_size = sizeof(msg);
}

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<PduHeader> && std::is_trivial_v<PduHeader>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<ClientInfoPdu> && std::is_trivial_v<ClientInfoPdu>);

#pragma pack(pop)

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
//#include <unistd.h>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVER_PORT 6767
#define RECEIVE_PORT 6868

struct ServerConnectionThread {
    void execute() {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        udp::endpoint const remote_endpoint = 
            udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(SERVER_IP), SERVER_PORT);
        udp::socket socket(io_service);
        socket.open(udp::v4());

        while (true) {
            ClientInfoPdu client_info_pdu;
            init_pdu(client_info_pdu);

            auto n = socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(&client_info_pdu, sizeof(client_info_pdu)), remote_endpoint);
            printf("sent %lu bytes\n", n);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
    }
};

int main(){ }
```

Comment: I really appreciate the long, detailed reply. I will say that I did some refactoring and ended up just including asio at a lower level and making use of its endianness functions, which resolved this issue. Your comments about undefined behavior are concerning though. I will say that this is the first time I've heard the term "POD" after 4 years of C++ development.

Comment: Could you point me to documentation that would show how what I originally posted would lead to undefined behavior?

Comment: @tyler124 [asio requires the memory buffer to be POD data](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) which is "common sense" for the C++ language as POD types are [the only types that you can copy/write with `memcpy` or equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c#comment44258135_146454).

Comment: Funnily enough, I ran into a separate issue involving POD today at work and referenced your answer. I think I'm understanding it better now. I appreciate you taking the time to help me learn!

Comment: @tyler124 Cheers! I rejected your edit as the `::value` addition is not required with the `*_v` traits. They were [added in c++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout) (see "Helper variable template"). So `traitX<T>::value` is equivalent to `traitX_v<T>`.Thanks again!